# Blazor - iterate through EditForm

Tags: html, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am building a (static) website in Blazor.wasm where the users upload some number of files.  My intention is then (after all the files have passed some basic checks) to iteratively present a set of fields which the users are asked to complete.  Only after they have submitted all the `[Required]` information and press submit will the next form show up.

I have included a minimal example below.

```
if (valid_files == numFiles)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < num_files; counter++)
        {

            paramList.Add(new ParamsForm { });
            <EditForm Model="@paramList[counter]" OnValidSubmit="@SingleSubmit">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary />
                <p>
                    Camera type <br>
                    <InputText id="cameratype" @bind-Value="@paramList[counter].CameraType" />
                </p>
                
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </EditForm>

        }
        <button @onclick="HandleValidSubmit">Upload Data </button>
    }
```

The expected behaviour is that on each iteration, a frech instance of the onbject `ParamsForm` is added to the list.  We then create a form based of that instance and wait for the user to complete the form.  Once they press the `Submit` button the next stage of the `for` loop begins.  Once all the data have been submitted and the `for` loop is completed, the `Upload data` button should appear and the users are invited to submit all their data to the server.

Instead, none of the code inside the `EditForm ...` section is being completed.  I.e. - I see no popping up of text boxes, and any code that I put in there (for example `@Console.WriteLine("This should show up)` does not seem to be executed.  The `Upload data` button does not appear and instead an error is thrown complaining that the `index is out of range`, which is weird because after the code at the top of the for loop there are no longer any elements being accessed by an index.

I am quite new to interacting between c# and HTML, so I think I can appreciate why what I have *shouldn't* work, but I don't know how I can go about writing something that will work.

Any advice would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much information about your class, where you are getting your file list from, and so on.  I recommend passing complete objects rather than individual properties.  For example, I'd rather have `IBrowserFile File {get; set;}` in my `ParamsForm` class than say `string FileName`.  That way, if I decide-- oh, I want to get this or that property-- it's already there.

Anyway, hope something in here might be useful:

```
@if (CurrentForm is not null)
{
    <EditForm Model="CurrentForm" OnValidSubmit="@SingleSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <p>
            Camera type <br>
            <InputText id="cameratype" @bind-Value="CurrentForm.CameraType" />
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
    @if (IsComplete) // Don't show upload button until you're done
    {
        <button @onclick="DoUploads">Upload Data </button>
    }
    @DisplayMessage
}

@code {
    class ParamsForm { public string FileName; public string CameraType; } // Just a placeholder
    List<ParamsForm> ParamsList = new List<ParamsForm>();
    ParamsForm CurrentForm { get; set; }
    int counter = 0;

    List<string> FileNames;
    bool IsComplete = false;
    string DisplayMessage = "";

    void InitializeForms()
    {
        // I don't know your class, so just an example
        foreach (var item in FileNames)
        {
            bool IsValid = false;
            // check file validity
            if (IsValid) ParamsList.Add(new ParamsForm() { FileName = item });
        }
        if(ParamsList.Count > 0)
            CurrentForm = ParamsList[0];
    }
    void SingleSubmit()
    {
        // Do stuff with CurrentForm
        if (++counter >= ParamsList.Count) IsComplete = true;
        else CurrentForm = ParamsList[counter];
    }
    async Task DoUploads()
    {
        // Do stuff with your ParamsList
        int UploadCounter = 0;
        foreach (ParamsForm item in ParamsList){
            DisplayMessage = "Uploading " + UploadCounter + " of " + ParamsList.Count;
            StateHasChanged();
            // Do the Upload;
        }
        DisplayMessage = "Finished.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is perfect, and taught me a little about Blazor too.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The ways of Blazor are a bit mysterious to me, too-- it takes a while to adjust!  I do know that Blazor has an OnAfterRender event, which makes me think that it might not like to have user input in a loop like that.  Or it may be that it's enumerating `if (valid_files == numFiles)` as false because those variables aren't initialized yet when the markup first renders.

I'd try two things:

(1) Throw `StateHasChanged()` at the end of your loop or after the code that sets `valid_files` and `numFiles` and see if that does anything you like.

(2) Probably this anyway: instead of looping in the markup, I'd build the entire `List<ParamsForm> paramsList` in the `FileInput`'s event handler instead, move the counter to the code block, and add `counter++` to the end of the `SingleSubmit()` method.

It's 5:00 am here, just got up to get a snack and going back to bed.  Let me know if things still don't fly, and I'll try a more complete example tomorrow. :D

Comment: So, you woke up just to answer his question ? Well, I'll vote your answer up for this...

Comment: I tried option (1) - it do not do something I like!  It seems that the whole program hangs.  Looking at the console all I can see is an increasing counter.  I'm not sure I understand option 2 though.  I can easily construct the list of ParamsForm in the FileInput's method as you suggest, similarly I can turn the for loop into a while and interate the counter in the SingleSubmit method.  Is that what you suggest?  I will try now anyway!